# JS .checked vs jquery attr('checked'), what is the difference?

Tags: javascript, jquery, attr, checked

I can't figure this one out.  According to [W3 Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_checkbox_checked.asp), *the checked property sets or returns the checked state of a checkbox.*

So why does `$('input').checked ? $('div').slideDown() : $('div').slideUp();` not work?

Using prop however, does work.

`$('input').prop('checked') ? $('div').slideDown() : $('div').slideUp();`

This is for a checkbox that is checked based on a database value.

Comment: Ones jQuery the other is not

Comment: Replace .attr() with .prop(), because .prop() is faster

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`checked` is a DOM element property so use it on DOM elements instead of jQuery objects.

```
$('input')[0].checked
```

if you have a jQuery object, use `prop` instead of `attr` since you are checking a property.  Just as a reference:

```
$("<input type='checkbox' checked='checked'>").attr("checked") // "checked"
$("<input type='checkbox' checked='foo'>").attr("checked") // "checked"
$("<input type='checkbox' checked>").attr("checked") // "checked"
$("<input type='checkbox'>").attr("checked") // undefined
```

Whereas `[0].getAttribute("checked")` will return the actual value.

`prop` will return `true` or `false` based on whether or not the attribute exists at all

Comment: If you wanted to actually check the attribute, would you use `attr` or `$('input')[0].getAttribute('checked')`?

Comment: @RobG I personally tend to use raw DOM over jQuery, but it would depend on the situation.  And `checked` is a bad example since value doesn't matter - it is a boolean attribute.

Comment: @RobG: jQuery does some stuff to boolean attributes, so you'd have to use `getAttribute` if you want the real value.

Comment: Yeah, jQuery's `attr` has been broken forever, just messing around. jQuery's mistake was trying to make attributes equivalent to properties.

Comment: why there is difference when i use `attr` and `[0].checked`..
when i used `[0].checked = true` then the checkbox got checked but when i tried `attr("checked","checked")` three times after unchecking through `removeAttr` then i found that third time checkbox was not checked but i tracked the object and i found that `checked="checked"` was there but `checked = false` was also there..

Answer (score 4):

`checked` is a property of the DOM object, not of the jQuery object. To make it work, you'd have to get the DOM object:

```
$('input')[0].checked;
```

You could also do `.is(':checked')`.

Answer (score 4):

In this case you need `prop()` rather than `attr()`,
replacing calls to `attr()` with `prop()` in your code will generally work.

**From** http://blog.jquery.com/2011/05/10/jquery-1-6-1-rc-1-released/

The difference between attributes and properties can be important in specific situations. **Before jQuery 1.6**, the `.attr()` method sometimes took property values into account when retrieving some attributes, which could cause inconsistent behavior. **As of jQuery 1.6**, the `.prop()` method provides a way to explicitly retrieve property values, while `.attr()`retrieves attributes.

`elem.checked`  ====  `true (Boolean)` Will change with checkbox state

`$(elem).prop("checked")` ==== `true (Boolean)` Will change with checkbox state

`elem.getAttribute("checked")`=====`"checked" (String)` Initial state of the checkbox; does not change

`$(elem).attr("checked") (1.6)` =====`"checked" (String)` Initial state of the checkbox; does not change

`$(elem).attr("checked") (1.6.1+)` ========`"checked" (String)` Will change with checkbox state

`$(elem).attr("checked") (pre-1.6)` =======`true (Boolean)` Changed with checkbox state

Also this url will help you more about your queries [.prop() vs .attr()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr)

A difference of `/is-checked-vs-attr-checked-checked/7` on http://jsperf.com/is-checked-vs-attr-checked-checked/7

Also to understand `The elements atttribute and properties` refer http://christierney.com/2011/05/06/understanding-jquery-1-6s-dom-attribute-and-properties/
http://jsperf.com/is-checked-vs-attr-checked-checked/7

Answer (score 0):

$('input') returns a JQuery object and it doesn't have checked property. You can use $('input')[0].checked.

Answer (score 0):

`$('input').attr('checked')` is outdated and one should use `$('input').prop('checked')`
Moreover, `$('input').checked` will not work as `$('input')` is the jquery object and `checked` is the property so that is why jquery has come up with `$('input').prop('checked')` to access the property.

However to convert jQuery object to DOM object you need to do
`$('input')[0].checked` this becomes the DOM Object and then you can access the property directly with `.`

But with jquery to access the property one should use this:

```
$('input').prop('checked') ? $('div').slideDown() : $('div').slideUp();
```

Hope this helps!!