# Jquery checkbox.checked always returns false

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$("tbody input[name='rooms_to_book']").on('change',function(){
    var current_row = $(this).closest("tr");
    var current_checkbox = current_row.find("input[name=checkbox]");
    if(current_checkbox.checked) {
        var price_per_night = parseFloat(current_row.find("td[name=price]").text().replace('$',''));
        var rooms_to_book = parseInt(current_row.find("input[name=rooms_to_book]").val());
        rooms_to_book = rooms_to_book ? rooms_to_book : 0;
        total_price = price_per_night * rooms_to_book;
    }else{
        total_price = 0;
    }
    current_row.find("td[name=total_price]").text('$'+ total_price);
});
```

The `current_checkbox.checked` always returns false, the html is correct.

Comment: The HTML may be correct but you need to add it to your question.

Comment: check this out might help you http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Comment: `checked` isn't a property of a jQuery object

Comment: possible duplicate of [JS .checked vs jquery attr('checked'), what is the difference?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15081335/js-checked-vs-jquery-attrchecked-what-is-the-difference)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

jQuery objects do not have a `checked` property. Replace

```
current_checkbox.checked
```

with

```
current_checkbox.prop('checked')
```

http://api.jquery.com/prop

Answer (score 5):

You are using current_checkbox.checked, checkbox has not any 'checked' properties, but you can use $('#id').is(':checked')

Answer (score 2):

You're using a jQuery element, not a DOM element. Use:

```
if(current_checkbox.prop("checked")) {

} //just for Steve <3
```

Answer (score 1):

`current_row.find("input[name=checkbox]")`

I'm fairly sure this returns a jQuery object, *not* the underlying checkbox element.

```
if(current_checkbox[0].checked)
```

Should work.