# how to select one check box and uncheck other in one time using js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is my code. Here I have given class name same for both the input check box:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('change', ".check_class", function() {
    $(".check_class").attr("checked", false); //uncheck all checkboxes
    $(this).attr("checked", true); //check the clicked one
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row  m-t-10 m-l-5">
  <div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <label class="checkbox-inline">  
        <input type="checkbox" class="check_class"  value="is_email" name="is_email">
        Email send?
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <label class="checkbox-inline"> 
        <input type="checkbox" class="check_class"  value="is_sms" name="is_sms">
        Sms send?
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried a lot but its still not working. Any mistakes. Thank you.

Comment: If only one of these checkboxes should be checked at a single time, just use a radio button - it's exactly what they were designed for.

Comment: no i need check box..

Comment: For what reason?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You code will work fine if you use `.prop()` instead of `.attr()` like below:-

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('change', ".check_class", function () {
    $(".check_class").prop("checked", false);
    $(this).prop("checked", true);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row  m-t-10 m-l-5">
    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
        <label class="checkbox-inline">  <input type="checkbox" class="check_class"  value="is_email" name="is_email">Email send?</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <label class="checkbox-inline"> <input type="checkbox" class="check_class"  value="is_sms" name="is_sms">Sms send?</label> 
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Note:- You can go for radio button, because they are specially designed to handle above scenario.

Reference:- [why .attr() not worked but .prop() worked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15081349/4248328)

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).on('change', ".check_class", function () {
         $(".check_class").each(function(index,element){
                  element.attr("checked", false);
         }); //uncheck all check-boxes

});
```

Answer (score 1):

If only one of these checkboxes should be checked at a single time, just use a radio button. It's exactly what they were designed for, and it saves the need for any JS code at all:

```html
<div class="row  m-t-10 m-l-5">
  <div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <label class="checkbox-inline">  
        <input type="radio" class="check_class" value="is_email" name="send">
        Email send?
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <label class="checkbox-inline"> 
        <input type="radio" class="check_class" value="is_sms" name="send">
        Sms send?
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `not(this)` to uncheck all other check boxes.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('change', ".check_class", function() {
    $(".check_class").not(this).prop('checked', false); 
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row  m-t-10 m-l-5">
  <div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <label class="checkbox-inline">  <input type="checkbox" class="check_class"  value="is_email" name="is_email">Email send?</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <label class="checkbox-inline"> <input type="checkbox" class="check_class"  value="is_sms" name="is_sms">Sms send?</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```